# listOf() returns MutableList

Tags: java, kotlin

In Kotlin, a list created using the `listOf()` function [(which should be immutable)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) passes a type check against `MutableList` using the `is` operator.

**Example:**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list = listOf("I'm immutable")

    println(list is MutableList)
}
```

will print

> true

Interestingly, an empty list created using `listOf<String>()` will fail the check and print **false** as it returns the singleton object `EmptyList`.

After some digging, it turns out that `mutableListOf()` creates a `java.util.ArrayList` whilst `listOf()` ends up creating a `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`, but none of the classes involved implement `MutableList`, so why does a non-empty list still pass the type check against it? Hence, is there an alternative way of reliably checking if a list is mutable without having to check against it's actual implementation (`is ArrayList` etc.)?

Comment: A `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is in fact mutable as you can replace elements. It is only fixed in size, so you can't add or remove elements. I think, Kotlin must have some internal mappings or ways to find out, if a Java list has the `mutable` property. An interface `MutableList` is not present in Java, it must be Kotlin specific.

Comment: `listOf` returns a SingletonList. Why `is` returns `true` here is a good question

Comment: Also, `list::class.java == MutableList::class.java` prints false. The class isn't the same, so I'm guessing there's a bug with the `is` operator or some of the code it compiles into. Looks like the `is` operator uses `TypeIntrinsics.isMutableList(list);` to check for the type.

Comment: It's still running on the JVM, where there isn't actually a runtime distinction between `MutableList` and `List` in the first place.  There's only a distinction at compile time.

Comment: @Zoe From looking at the [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.70/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/collections/CollectionsJVM.kt#L18), I was under the impression that singletonList() was just a function that returns an immutable list, but my debugger does show that with a single argument, the list is of type Collections$SingletonList so it appears you're correct there. With two or more arguments, an Arrays$ArrayList is created instead, not that I know the practical difference between the two anyway.

Comment: They're both basically the same, except SingletonList is preferred for single-item lists. If you use `Arrays.asArray` and pass one argument in IntelliJ, the IDE will suggest using `singletonList` instead. . Both are immutable, but I'm really not sure why `is` returns true here

Comment: @LouisWasserman The docs state that "_Currently, the listOf method is implemented using an array list, but in future more memory-efficient fully immutable collection types could be returned that exploit the fact that they know they can't change_". I understand that it is just an interface, but if the point of the interface is to declare the intention of being mutable or not, surely a check like this should be important?

Comment: Evidently they made the decision that runtime `is` checks weren't as relevant as the compile-time interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The separation between `List` and `MutableList` is an illusion created by the Kotlin compiler. At runtime, Kotlin uses Java collection classes, which only have a single `List` interface containing both read and mutation methods. Compile-time references to `List` and `MutableList` are both compiled to `java.util.List` references. Therefore, it's not possible to detect whether a list is a `MutableList` at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Couldn't `MutableList` just have inherited from `java.util.List` then (at compile-time), maintaining the distinction between the two?

Comment: No, because Kotlin uses Java collections as implementation classes, not only as interface definitions, and `java.util.ArrayList` does not implement any Kotlin interfaces.

Comment: That's actually stated on their docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html - "Currently, the listOf method is implemented using an array list, but in future more memory-efficient fully immutable collection types could be returned that exploit the fact that they know they can't change."

Comment: A bit of clarification is needed. The Kdoc for List does not describe it as immutable, only that it exposes solely "read-only" methods. There should never be an expectation that a List is immutable unless the function that returns it specifies that it is immutable in the Kdoc. It's a common design pattern for a class to hold a private MutableList but expose that same instance as a read-only List. Users cannot expect the List to be immutable in this situation, any more than they can assume accessing a `val` property will always return the same value (`val` means read-only, not constant).

Comment: And so it *is* possible to detect if a List is a MutableList. It's just not really useful to do so. `listOf()` with a single argument truly does return a List that is not a MutableList, and its Kdoc reflects that fact. Some of the `listOf()` function overloads do not claim to return an immutable List, only a read-only List.