# Hibernate randomly throws error: Cannot coerce value `[]` [java.util.ArrayList] as Long

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm encountering unstable errors when using a parameter of type List with my repository methods. The issue seems to be related to the interoperability between Kotlin lists and Java. When I run my unit test, it fails randomly, and I suspect this has something to do with the MutableList returned by listOf() in Kotlin. More information can be found in this StackOverflow post: [listOf() returns MutableList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580173/listof-returns-mutablelist).

Here's an example of my unit test and repository method:

```kotlin
            @Test
            fun `should return recipes with the specified author, locale and categories`() {
                println("AuthorID: " + author.id)

                recipeRepo.findRecipesBy(
                    locale = LanguageSelection.ENGLISH,
                    authorIds = arrayListOf(44),
                )
                // it throws before reaching asserts
            }
```

Repository:

```kotlin
interface RecipeRepository : JpaRepository<Recipe, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT r FROM Recipe r WHERE "
            + "(:authorIds is null or r.author.id in (:authorIds)) "
            + "and (:recipeIds is null or r.id in (:recipeIds)) "
            + "and (:minPrice is null or r.estimatedPrice >= :minPrice) "
            + "and (:maxPrice is null or r.estimatedPrice <= :maxPrice) "
            + "and ( cast(:beforeDate as timestamp) is null or r.createdAt < cast(:beforeDate as timestamp)) "
            + "and ( cast(:afterDate as timestamp) is null or r.createdAt > cast(:afterDate as timestamp)) "
            + "and (:minLikeCount is null or r.likeCount >= :minLikeCount) "
            + "and (:categoryIds is null or exists(select rc from r.categories rc where rc.id in (:categoryIds))) "
    )

    fun findRecipesBy(
        @Param("authorIds") authorIds: ArrayList<Long>? = null,
        @Param("recipeIds") recipeIds: ArrayList<Long>? = null,
        @Param("minPrice") minPrice: Double? = null,
        @Param("maxPrice") maxPrice: Double? = null,
        @Param("beforeDate") beforeDate: Date? = null,
        @Param("afterDate") afterDate: Date? = null,
        @Param("minLikeCount") minLikeCount: Int? = null,
        @Param("categoryIds") categoryIds: ArrayList<Long>? = null,
        sort: Sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdAt"),
    ): List<Recipe>

}
```

Error:

```
Parameter value [[44]] did not match expected type [BasicSqmPathSource(id : Long) ]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [[44]] did not match expected type [BasicSqmPathSource(id : Long) ]
    at app//org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371)
    at app//org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)
    at app//org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:94)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at app/jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy189.findRecipesBy(Unknown Source)
    at app//com.fittastetic.fittastetic_backend.shared.recipe.repository.RecipeRepository$DefaultImpls.findRecipesBy$default(RecipeRepository.kt:38)
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CoercionException: Cannot coerce value `[44]` [java.util.ArrayList] as Long
    at app//org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongJavaType.coerce(LongJavaType.java:155)
    at app//org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongJavaType.coerce(LongJavaType.java:24)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.coerce(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:144)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:111)
    ... 141 more
```

Comment: It intermittently, create issues with the list, as it internally uses hibernate, prefer to use native query in this case.

Comment: What is the exact error message (the question title might have mangled it a little), and where is it thrown? It might also help to see your `Recipe` class.

Comment: I  added the error log. The recipe class is really basic, but I can add it too, if it would help you.

Comment: you can log the generated sql and then try to execute it in sqldeveloper, maybe you'll find something related to the mapping. https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Hibernate team [completely redesigned query model in HBN6](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sqm-semantic-query-model/), that is expected something have stopped working, especially for cases like yours which actually looks like a hack/trick. Here I would suggest to ask a question on [HBN forum](https://discourse.hibernate.org/c/hibernate-orm/5).

However, some workarounds do exist:

I. idiomatic way to implement such queries is to use jpa specifications, something like:

```java
public interface RecipeRepository extends JpaRepository<Recipe, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Recipe> {

    default List<Recipe> findRecipesBy(List<Long> authorIds, List<Long> recipeIds) {
        Specification<Recipe> specification = (root, cq, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (authorIds != null && !authorIds.isEmpty()) {
                predicates.add(root.get("author").get("id").in(authorIds));
            }
            if (recipeIds != null && !recipeIds.isEmpty()) {
                predicates.add(root.get("id").in(recipeIds));
            }
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
        return findAll(specification);
    }
    
}
```

II. trick with `coalesce` - seems to be applicable for PostgreSQL only:

```java
@Query("SELECT r FROM Recipe r WHERE "
            + "(coalesce(:authorIds) is null or r.author.id in (:authorIds)) "
            + "and (coalesce(:recipeIds) is null or r.id in (:recipeIds)) "
            + "and (:minPrice is null or r.estimatedPrice >= :minPrice) "
            + "and (:maxPrice is null or r.estimatedPrice <= :maxPrice) "
            + "and ( cast(:beforeDate as timestamp) is null or r.createdAt < cast(:beforeDate as timestamp)) "
            + "and ( cast(:afterDate as timestamp) is null or r.createdAt > cast(:afterDate as timestamp)) "
            + "and (:minLikeCount is null or r.likeCount >= :minLikeCount) "
            + "and (coalesce(:categoryIds) is null or exists(select rc from r.categories rc where rc.id in (:categoryIds))) "
    )
```

III. trick with SpEL - delegate null checks to SpEL:

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Recipe r WHERE "
            + "(:#{#authorIds == null} = true or r.author.id in (:authorIds)) "
            + "and (:#{#recipeIds == null} = true or r.id in (:recipeIds)) "
            + "and (:minPrice is null or r.estimatedPrice >= :minPrice) "
            + "and (:maxPrice is null or r.estimatedPrice <= :maxPrice) "
            + "and ( cast(:beforeDate as timestamp) is null or r.createdAt < cast(:beforeDate as timestamp)) "
            + "and ( cast(:afterDate as timestamp) is null or r.createdAt > cast(:afterDate as timestamp)) "
            + "and (:minLikeCount is null or r.likeCount >= :minLikeCount) "
            + "and (:#{#categoryIds == null} = true or exists(select rc from r.categories rc where rc.id in (:categoryIds))) "
    )
```

Comment: Looks good, I will test it out later. Basically all I want to achieve is to have optional parameters and thats my solution to solve this problem

Comment: Do you know which one of your solutions would be the best performance wise?

Comment: in general, attempt to cover all possible user inputs by a single query is not a good idea - typically, DBs maintain just a couple of execution plans for single SQL, thinking those plans will be optimal for all possible combinations of user input is too naive, so, from DB perspective the best option is to build specific query for specific input - that is option I.