# JPA HQL Query - how to check some value of inner elements of the array

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Today I Have this filter. It's working.

```
@Query(value =  "SELECT DISTINCT e from SocialEvent e "
        + "join e.multiPropsValuesSet m "
        + "WHERE ( "
        + "((m in ?1   OR COALESCE(?1, NULL) is null )"     
        +")"
        +" AND  (COALESCE(?2, NULL) is null  OR m in ?2 ) "
        + "AND  (COALESCE(?3, NULL) is null  OR m in ?3 ) "
        + ") "
        + "AND "
        + "((e.fromAge BETWEEN ?4 AND ?5) "
        + "OR (e.toAge BETWEEN ?4 AND ?5)"
        + "OR (?4 BETWEEN e.fromAge AND e.toAge )) "
        + "AND (e.date BETWEEN ?6 AND ?7) "
        + "ORDER BY e.date ASC"   /*, nativeQuery=true - cause errror*/)
List<SocialEvent> filter16Main(
        List <MultiPropValue> eventTypes,
        List <MultiPropValue> areas, List <MultiPropValue> jewLvlKeep,
        int fromAge, int toAge,
        Date from , Date to);
```

The List  eventTypes, Represent a set (list) of some objects.

Each MultiPropValue have a connectedValuesIds that is List.

**I want to add to the query a condition that will search inside of each item of connected values.**

**For example I want to add this:**

```
@Query(value =  "SELECT DISTINCT e from SocialEvent e "
            + "join e.multiPropsValuesSet m "
            + "WHERE ( "
            + "(("
            + "(m in ?1   OR COALESCE(?1, NULL) is null )"
            + " OR "
            + "(m.id in ?1.connectedValuesIds ) "   //--->new condition.    
            +")"
            +" AND  (COALESCE(?2, NULL) is null  OR m in ?2 ) "
            + "AND  (COALESCE(?3, NULL) is null  OR m in ?3 ) "
            + ") "
            + "AND "
            + "((e.fromAge BETWEEN ?4 AND ?5) "
            + "OR (e.toAge BETWEEN ?4 AND ?5)"
            + "OR (?4 BETWEEN e.fromAge AND e.toAge )) "
            + "AND (e.date BETWEEN ?6 AND ?7) "
            + "ORDER BY e.date ASC"   /*, nativeQuery=true - cause errror*/)
    List<SocialEvent> filter16Main(
            List <MultiPropValue> eventTypes,
            List <MultiPropValue> areas, List <MultiPropValue> jewLvlKeep,
            int fromAge, int toAge,
            Date from , Date to);
```

I know that the steps that I need is:

1. Get all the connectedValuesIds from the set items.
2. Check if m.id is found there.

**In other words - I want to check some props of the inner elements of the set**

The above code generates this error, when starting up the app:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 1. near line 1, column 178 [SELECT DISTINCT e from com.lingar.SocialEvents.socialEvent.entities.SocialEvent e join e.multiPropsValuesSet m WHERE ( (((m in ?1   OR COALESCE(?1, NULL) is null ) OR (m.id in ?1.connectedValuesIds ) ) AND  (COALESCE(?2, NULL) is null  OR m in ?2 ) AND  (COALESCE(?3, NULL) is null  OR m in ?3 ) ) AND ((e.fromAge BETWEEN ?4 AND ?5) OR (e.toAge BETWEEN ?4 AND ?5)OR (?4 BETWEEN e.fromAge AND e.toAge )) AND (e.date BETWEEN ?6 AND ?7) ORDER BY e.date ASC]
```

I have tried many things and have googled it a lot.

I prefer not to make a major changes in the exist query.

**What is the correct way to achieve it in simple way?**

Other related code:

**The entity:**

```
public class SocialEvent {
    
    
    //...
    @ManyToMany
    @CollectionTable(name="social_events_multi_values")
    private Set<MultiPropValue> multiPropsValuesSet = new HashSet<MultiPropValue>();
```

**Parent of MultiPropValue:**

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class TextPiece {
    //...
    @ElementCollection
        @CollectionTable    
        private List<Long> connectedValuesIds = new ArrayList<>();
 }
```

**MultiPropValue:**

```
public class MultiPropValue extends TextPiece{
    private @Id 
//...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to create utility method which extracts list of ids and take advantage of SpEL, something like:

```java
package tld;

...

public interface SocialEventRepository extends JpaRepository<SocialEvent, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT e from SocialEvent e "
            + "join e.multiPropsValuesSet m "
            + "WHERE ( "
            + "(("
            + "(m in ?1   OR COALESCE(?1, NULL) is null )"
            + " OR "
            + "(m.id in (:#{T(tld.SocialEventRepository).extractIds(#eventTypes)})) "   //--->new condition.
            + ")"
            + " AND  (COALESCE(?2, NULL) is null  OR m in ?2 ) "
            + "AND  (COALESCE(?3, NULL) is null  OR m in ?3 ) "
            + ") "
            + "AND "
            + "((e.fromAge BETWEEN ?4 AND ?5) "
            + "OR (e.toAge BETWEEN ?4 AND ?5)"
            + "OR (?4 BETWEEN e.fromAge AND e.toAge )) "
            + "AND (e.date BETWEEN ?6 AND ?7) "
            + "ORDER BY e.date ASC")
    List<SocialEvent> filter16Main(
            List<MultiPropValue> eventTypes,
            List<MultiPropValue> areas, List<MultiPropValue> jewLvlKeep,
            int fromAge, int toAge,
            Date from, Date to);

    static List<Long> extractIds(List<MultiPropValue> values) {
        return values.stream().map(MultiPropValue::getConnectedValuesIds)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

However, I would recommend to [move to Criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75572804/3426309)

Comment: Thanks, interesting. After trying what you offer I get this error:

Type cannot be found 'my.package'] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E: Type cannot be found 'my.package'

Comment: I would be happy to get some good reference to learn the query Spel, since this doc is very short and looks lack. 

https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions

Comment: I'm not sure if there is much to learn, the "magic" happens in `org.springframework.data.repository.query.SpelQueryContext` class: `spring-data` just parses query string and considers `?#{...}` and `:#{...}` expressions as extra query bind parameters with values resolved in runtime

Comment: Thanks I have tried to solve in other way, if you can take a look here I would appreciate it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75781973/jpql-with-positional-parameter-problem-when-empty-list-set-provided

Comment: That won't work in new HBN versions: [HHH-15743](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15743)