# JPQL custom search query in repository

Tags: java, jpql, jparepository

Here is my **Item** class.

```
public class Item extends BaseEntity {
    private String modelName;
    private int discount;
    private double price;

    @ManyToOne
    private Collection collection;

    private boolean isChild;

    private String article;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne
    private SubType subType;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Material> materials;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Color> colors;

    @ManyToOne
    private Gender gender;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Picture> pictures;
}
```

I want to have a search query in my ItemRepository, but don't know where I can find tutorials on creating such method. This is what chatGPT have created.

```
@Query("SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE " +
            "(:modelName IS NULL OR i.modelName LIKE %:modelName%) AND " +
            "(:minPrice IS NULL OR i.price >= :minPrice) AND " +
            "(:maxPrice IS NULL OR i.price <= :maxPrice) AND " +
            "(:brandIds IS NULL OR i.collection.brand.id IN (:brandIds)) AND " +
            "(:typeIds IS NULL OR i.subType.type.id IN (:typeIds)) AND " +
            "(:materials IS NULL OR i.materials = :materials) AND " +
            "(:colors IS NULL OR i.colors = :colors) AND " +
            "(:child IS NULL OR i.isChild = :child) AND " +
            "(:genderId IS NULL OR i.gender.id = :genderId)")
    List<Item> searchItems(
            @Param("modelName") String modelName,
            @Param("minPrice") Double minPrice,
            @Param("maxPrice") Double maxPrice,
            @Param("brandIds") List<Long> brandIds,
            @Param("typeIds") List<Long> typeIds,
            @Param("materials") Set<Material> materials,
            @Param("colors") Set<Color> colors,
            @Param("child") Boolean child,
            @Param("genderId") Long genderId
    );
```

It is not working, and giving this error

*2023-04-12 12:20:59.121 ERROR 11924 --- [nio-8000-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'is null) and (null=null or . is null) and (0 is null or item0_.is_child=0) an...' at line 1
2023-04-12 12:21:23.398 ERROR 11924 --- [nio-8000-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
*

**Do you know sources where I can find docs about creating search query?**

Working search method.

Comment: [stop writing unreliable queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75572804/3426309)

Answer (score 0):

To generate dynamic query you should use either `Querydsl` or `JPA Criteria` query. The way you have implemented is very complex and you will not able to achieve all the scenario.

To use Querydsl follow https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-querydsl

To use JPA Criteria check https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries