# Unknown wrap conversion requested after migrating to spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am getting below exception for a jpa query

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown wrap conversion requested: java.util.ArrayList to java.lang.string: 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringJavaType'
```

The Jpa query is

```
@Query(value ="select s from table s where (coalesce(:users,1)='1' or s.user in :users) and "
        + "(coalesce(:employees,1)='1' or s.employee in :employees) and "
        + "(:number=null or s.salary=:number)")
List<TableEntity> findTable(@Param("users") List<String> users,
        @Param("employees") List<String> employees,
        @Param("number" Long number),
        Pageable paging);
```

where `users` and `employees` are `List<String>` which can be null. I started seeing this exception after migrating to spring boot 3.0.4.

Comment: I think it should be `@Param("clients") List<String> clients` instead of `@Param("clients" List<String> clients)`

Comment: Also, I see a parameter `users` in the query which is not supplied as the argument, and a parameter `clients` supplied in the method which is not used in the query. Can you share the actual code?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran That was a typo while adding the question. In the actual code I have written it properly.

Comment: yes, i suggest to improve the query ... [mre] would be helpful :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate randomly throws error: Cannot coerce value \`\[\]\` \[java.util.ArrayList\] as Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75556114/hibernate-randomly-throws-error-cannot-coerce-value-java-util-arraylist)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I tried all the solutions but it did not work . I am getting the same exception

Comment: Any luck with this?