# Hibernate 6 IN clause

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

Since upgrading to Spring Boot 3/ Hibernate 6, all my repository querys with IN clause fail.

```
    @Query ("SELECT p "
        + "FROM Package p "
        + "WHERE (:description is null or lower(p.description) LIKE %:description%) "
        + "AND (:name is null or lower(p.name) LIKE %:name%) "
        + "AND (:active is null or p.active = :active) "
        + "AND ((:operators) is null or p.operator.id IN (:operators)) ")
Page<Package> findCoincidencesWithoutItemReference(
                                        @Param ("description") String description,
                                        @Param ("name") String name,
                                        @Param ("active") boolean active,
                                        @Param ("operators") List<Integer> operators,
                                        Pageable page);
```

In the example above in the IN (:operators) when I pass elements to the List operators I get the errror:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [[1]] did not match expected type [BasicSqmPathSource(id : Integer) ]
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CoercionException: Cannot coerce value `[1]` [java.util.ArrayList] as Integer
```

have tried to chage it to IN :operators with the same result.

Any idea why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate randomly throws error: Cannot coerce value \`\[\]\` \[java.util.ArrayList\] as Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75556114/hibernate-randomly-throws-error-cannot-coerce-value-java-util-arraylist)