# Null condition in Jpa @Query

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a query in JPA, but all parameters should be optional. I tried many different ways, but none were successful because they threw some error.

If for example the given list of job Types is empty it should evaluate this condition as true. Currently no companies would be queried.

```
@Query("""
        select c from Company c
        where ((EXISTS (select 1 from CompanyJobType cjt JOIN JobType jt on cjt.jobType = jt where jt.name in :jobTypes and cjt.company = c)))
        AND ((EXISTS (select 1 from CompanyIndustry ci JOIN Industry i on ci.industry = i where i.name in :industries and ci.company = c)))
        AND (c.name like %:search% or c.shortDescription like %:search%)
        AND (c.isStartup = :isStartup OR :isStartup = false)
        AND c.talentpoolOpen = true
        """)
Page<Company> find(List<String> jobTypes, List<String> industries, String search, boolean isStartup, Pageable pageable);
```

If you have any other approach how to get this to work, I'm happy to adapt every part.

Comment: This type of requirement is not fit for a statically defined query string - you need to define the query on the fly based on the given parameters. JPA has criteria api for this purpose, so you can then determine if jobTypes was defined and needs to be added to the query or just ignored and skipped without burdening your database with null checks. Spring has JPA Specifications built around it - see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when we know that the parameter or list of parameters can be optional aka null the `@Query` should know it:

Can you try next one query and tell me if it is going to fix the problem:

```
  @Query("""
        select c from Company c
        where ((:jobTypes) is null or (EXISTS (select 1 from CompanyJobType cjt JOIN JobType jt on cjt.jobType = jt where jt.name in :jobTypes and cjt.company = c)))
        AND ((:industries) is null or (EXISTS (select 1 from CompanyIndustry ci JOIN Industry i on ci.industry = i where i.name in :industries and ci.company = c)))
        AND ((:search) is null or (c.name like %:search% or c.shortDescription like %:search%))
        AND ((:isStartup) is null or (c.isStartup = :isStartup OR :isStartup = false))
        AND c.talentpoolOpen = true
        """)
  Page<Company> find(List<String> jobTypes, List<String> industries, String search, boolean isStartup, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: If I do that it works like a charm when the list is null, but if I ad 1 element I get:
Unknown wrap conversion requested: java.util.ArrayList to java.lang.String : `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringJavaType` (java.lang.String)

Comment: I am sure you are using a version of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` > 3.x, in this case under starter is hibernate version >6.x that  hibernate team made some redesign on query model. I think this is an topic for another question. By the way i suggest you to check approved answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75556114/hibernate-randomly-throws-error-cannot-coerce-value-java-util-arraylist)(as a workaround) also from there you will find a reference to [Vlad Mihalcea blogs](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sqm-semantic-query-model/) where he explains it.

Comment: And also if you will downgrade the version of framework you will see that the query provided into answer, work well.

Comment: The workaround worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, I usually opt for `COALESCE` jpa function (which maps any null value to a constant string), allowing to avoid the tricky "OR" part.

For instance:

`WHERE CompanyJobType like COALESCE(:JobType, '%')`

When the JobType param is null, the where clause will be always true (ie CompanyJobType like '%'

Simple but effective :-)